# Debugging symbols for msado15.dll or msxml3.dll under VS2012 in a VC++ COM+ DLL

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, unmanaged, inspector

When I attach to Dllhost process to debug a VC++ COM+ component, the debugger activates and stops on the breakpoints, so I know that debugging part works.

But I cannot inspect any objects in the code such as

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMAttributePtr
MSXML2::IXMLDOMElementPtr
_RecordsetPtr
```

because for them the inspector is showing the error messages

```
{0x02c09568 <No type information available in symbol file for msado15.dll> {...}}
{0x00a17744 <No type information available in symbol file for msxml3.dll> {...}}
```

The symbols have been obtained by going into Tools/Options menu of VS2012, switching to Debugging/Symbols tree and hitting "Load all symbols" button". Apparently that did download something for the above mentioned DLLs, as previously I was getting another error

```
Information not available, symbols not loaded for ...dll
```

for each of the DLLs.

I find it unlikely that unluckily I am trying to inspect just a handful of classes that are missing symbol information in an otherwise populated symbol file, so obviously something is wrong with the environment that I inherited with the machine. What do I need to do to be able to inspect the objects from the COM DLLs?

Thank you!

Comment: They are interface pointers.  Pretty essential feature of COM, it strictly separates the implementation from the interface.  So you can't see the implementation, and the debugger doesn't know it either, it is buried inside those DLLs.  Focus on debugging your own code, those DLLs don't have a bug.

Comment: So when I have a variable declared such as `_RecordsetPtr p` can I not inspect `p`? How does that make any sense?

Comment: And let me ask you, how come when `p` is returned to the classic ASP page, than I can inspect the object it would be assigned to? It would be of type `_Recordset` there by the time. I am editing the question to point out the differences.